# Comment some lines in a text file using python

Tags: python, scripting

I'm new to python and I just started learning the basics.

I'm trying to create a program that will take a file and comment (using # ) the lines that don't have anything after the equal sign.

For example,

> **V12 =**
>
> **V13 = 3**

Should be

> **#V12 =**
>
> **V13 = 3**

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this I would keep it simple and read from one file and write to another.

```
with open('/path/to/myfile') as infile:
   with open('/path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
      for line in infile:
         if line.rstrip().endswith('='):
             outfile.write('#' + line + '\n')
         else:
             outfile.write(line + '\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you'll need to read in the file. Then, check each line. If the line has something after you split on the equal sign, just output the line as is; otherwise, append a hashtag to the front and then output the line.

```
f = open(filename, "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

output_lines = []
for line in lines:
    if len(line.split("=")[1]) > 0:
       output_lines.append(line)
    else:
       output_lines.append("#" + line)
f = open("commented" + filename, "w")
f.write("\n".join(output_lines))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that you can run like:

```
python comment.py < infile > outfile
```

comment.py:

```
import sys

# stdin/stdout live in sys
# "for line in file" reads each line of the file, returning the text
# of the line including the trailing newline
for line in sys.stdin:
    if line.strip().endswith('='):
        line = "#" + line
    # print command adds a trailing newline, so we have to use all but
    # the last character of our input line
    print(line[:-1])
```

You can get a lot fancier using the `re` module for regular expressions.

Given infile:

```
V12 = 'hello'
V23 = 'world'
V34 =
```

produces:

```
V12 = 'hello'
V23 = 'world'
#V34 =
```

Comment: @mattsap, is this better?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this code to accomplish your task. The only restriction is that the empty variable is identified by no whitespace. E.g. 'v1='

```
MyFile=open("AFile.txt", 'r+');
newdata = []
data = MyFile.readlines()
for item in data:
    PosEquals = item.find('=')
    LenOfItem  = len(item)
    # Checks position of equals in line 
    # and also if there is anything after equal sign
    if PosEquals <> -1 and PosEquals <> LenOfItem-1:
        newdata.append(item)
    else:
        newdata.append('#'+item)
MyFile.seek(0)
MyFile.writelines(newdata)    
MyFile.close()
```